# ¿Por qué undefined, en vez del elemento?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Intento obtener el elemento anterior al elemento que tiene la clase `cp` y se encuentre en el índice 1, pero me escribe undefined, envez del contenido del H2

```js
var b =document.getElementsByClassName("cp")[1].previousSibling.innerHTML;


var c = document.body.innerHTML = b;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
 <style>
   .cp {
     position: absolute;
     color: red;
     text-align: left;   
     
   }
   
  </style>
<body>
  <p style="text-align:center;">Este nuevo episodio, contaremos muchas cosas..</p>
  <b class="cp">Capitulo I:</b>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Maximo y minimo</h2>
  
  <b class="cp">Capitulo II:</b>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque `.previousSibling` devuelve el `Node` anterior que no es el `<h2>` sino el espacio en blanco que hay entre el `>` de cierre del `<h2>` hasta el `<` al inicio del `<b>`

```
                                                      "

  "
```

El elemento que buscas es uno antes de ese, así que puedes usar

```
previousSibling.previousSibling
```

O mejor aún

```
previousElementSibling
```

que ignora los espacios en blanco

Ejemplo:

```js
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("cp")[1].previousElementSibling.innerHTML;


var c = document.body.innerHTML = b;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
 <style>
   .cp {
     position: absolute;
     color: red;
     text-align: left;   
     
   }
   
  </style>
<body>
  <p style="text-align:center;">Este nuevo episodio, contaremos muchas cosas..</p>
  <b class="cp">Capitulo I:</b>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Maximo y minimo</h2>

  <b class="cp">Capitulo II:</b>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Carlos Muñoz

Comment: una pregunta, cual es el tipo de nodo de los espacios?

Comment: `.nodeType`: `3` `.nodeName`: `"#text"`

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta por una mejor, ya que lo de los espacios en blanco no funciona igual en IE

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias